I am trying to connect to sharepoint with python, using the following code -
I am trying to connect to sharepoint with python, using the following code.
This is my code.
#import all the libraries
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 
import io
import pandas as pd

#target url taken from sharepoint and credentials
url = 'https://company.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Folder%20Number1/Folder%20Number2/Folder3/Folder%20Number4/Target_Excel_File_v4.xlsx?cid=_Random_letters_and_numbers-21dbf74c'
username = 'Dumby_account@company.com'
password = 'Password!'

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
    ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()
    print("Authentication successful")
else:
    response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)

This gives me the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\ssl.py:1383 in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\ssl.py:1383 in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py:501 in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\office365\runtime\auth\providers\saml_token_provider.py:114 in get_authentication_cookie
    logger.error(e.response.text)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

I am trying to access an excel file in sharepoint
